# How to deal with font loading and screenshots in Cypress

Tags: fonts, screenshot, cypress

I have tested the [`cypress-image-snapshot`](https://github.com/palmerhq/cypress-image-snapshot) plugin which uses `cy.screenshot`. It works, but the problem is that fonts sometimes doesn't load in time for the screenshot so we end up with a very unstable diff.

Is there a way to make cypress wait for fonts to be loaded and UI to be updated before continuing with its tests?

Comment: @font: not sure if this is possible, but please take a look at my example here: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/testing-dom__performance-metrics Maybe you can check whether the font has been loaded with this method

Comment: @ui-update: neither the screenshot plugin nor cypress knows when the browser or your AUT is ready. So you should find some conditions (e.g. is a specific element in the DOM?). You also can try to publish specific window events in your AUT if it is loaded in cypress. I tried this within our AUT at work and the aurelia event hub, works very well.

Answer (score 5):

Try the [FontFaceSet API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fonts):

```js
cy.document().its("fonts.status").should("equal", "loaded")
```

The assertion automatically makes the test wait until the `document.fonts.status` to be `"loaded"`. Since it's an experimental technology by now, you should check its browser compatibility first.

Comment: This waits for the font status to change to loaded, but there is still a timing issue where loaded font is applied.  It still takes the snapshot with the fallback font.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by waiting on the fonts my app needs. For example

```
  cy.document().then((doc) => {
    cy.wrap(doc.fonts).invoke("check", '16px GothamBold').should("be.true")
    cy.wrap(doc.fonts).invoke("check", '16px GothamBook').should("be.true")
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of using the [FontFaceApi](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet/ready)

```
cy.document()
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet/ready
  // The promise will only resolve once the document has completed loading fonts,
  // layout operations are completed, and no further font loads are needed.
  .then(document => document.fonts.ready)
  .then(value => {
    cy.log('Font loading completed');
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be solved by checking the font family attribute on elememts. For example if you were using `Roboto` you would do something like:

```js
  cy.get('{{your selector here}}')
    .should('have.css', 'font-family')
    .and('match', /Roboto/);
```

More here:
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should#Yields